# Creating BAT File From server to c:\Program files

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I'm trying to make a bat file that transfers two or three files from my server to my PC. I kept getting invalid number of parameters. I;m running Windows 7 btw.

So far this is what i came up with

```
@echo OFF
@echo Updating EXE

xcopy \\gronk\shared\ZInstaller\latest\*.* %ProgramFiles%\ZInstaller /D /U /Y
@echo.

@echo Update Complete!
@echo.
pause
```

Comment: Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

on my computer, the programfiles var contains a space:

```
C:\Document and Settings>echo %programfiles%
C:\Program Files
```

i think xcopy interprets this as 2 parameters, therefore you have one too more parameter. Try escaping `%ProgramFiles%\ZInstaller` with double quotes: `"%ProgramFiles%\ZInstaller"`...

Comment: Thanks, but now i get Invalid drive specification 0file(s) copied.
Most probably have to do with these lines

\\gronk\shared\ZInstaller\latest\*.*

I'm trying to not use the mapped network drive involved as i'm creating this bat on multiple computers with different mapped drive.

And the server i have, has a user password account in order to log in.

Comment: @StrangerfromFarCoastr Did you try to `dir \\gronk\shared\ZInstaller\latest*.*`?

Answer (score 0):

Quote all paths that might contain spaces, and use **robocopy** instead to deal with UNC paths better.

The equivalent of `/D` and `/U` should be `/XO` and `/XL` respectively.

Comment: I got invalid parameter #1 : \\gronk\shared\ZInstaller\latest\*.* with and without quotes.

Comment: As `robocopy /?` says, the usage is `robocopy source destination [file [file]...] [options]`, where source/dest are directory names and the file list (in your case latest*.*) is specified separately at the end. Did you simply use `robocopy "\\gronk\shared\ZInstaller\latest\*.*" "%ProgramFiles%\ZInstaller"`?

Comment: Yes i did. How should it be if it's not that?

Comment: I mentioned the usage above: source dir, then destination dir and finally file list.

Comment: robocopy "\\standardmssql\sishared\Biims_SISB\latest" "%ProgramFiles%\BIIMS" /XO /XL

I tried out your method, after running into numnerous errors. This one works HOWEVER, a new error pops up

Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Is there any other lines i should add? Also i have to run the batch as admin which is a fuss.

Comment: %ProgramFiles% is your *destination*? Since you're ordinarily not allowed to write there that's probably why it's asking for admin access.

Comment: But running it as admin negates that, right? what about the "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password" error?

Comment: Even admin users are ordinarily not allowed to create new files in system folders such as Program Files (the "New" menu shows only "Folder"), nor can you simply double-click a text file in program Files, edit in Notepad and save it back. Try running the batch file from an elevated command prompt and see if that helps.

Comment: Running it on cmd as admin and still the same error. robocopy "\\gronk\shared\ZInstaller\latest" "%ProgramFiles%\ZInstaller" /XO /XL

Comment: Are you sure your account has the requisite permissions to access that folder? Try setting permissions to allow "Everyone" access to the source folder.

Comment: Hi Karan thanks for replying. I had already did that, gave full permission to Everyone.The OS that i'm connecting to is a Windows Server 2008. I have created a share account with username and password on it.

Comment: Still seems to be a permissions problem; see if [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d40f29ab-ca1d-4f94-b6d8-102c5523f222/copy-folder-to-remote-computer-robocopyexe) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other comments/answers it's obvious that the command should contain quotes:

```
xcopy \\gronk\shared\ZInstaller\latest\*.* "%ProgramFiles%\ZInstaller" /D /U /Y
```

With the additional errors you are getting, try to issue a

```
dir \\gronk\shared\ZInstaller\latest*.*
```

and

```
dir "%ProgramFiles%\ZInstaller"
```

To see which of the two parameters are causing the invalid drive error